# Bridge Unix domain socket with a FIFO and log file

Tags: bash, sockets, shell, unix, fifo

I need to write a script - preferably a bash script - that will listen on a Unix domain socket and pipe the output to a log file while receiving input through a FIFO. The FIFO / log end is supposed to mimic the style of [ii](http://tools.suckless.org/ii/). The script also be able to monitor and react to the input from the FIFO (e.g. for a "stop" function).

This is as far as I got:

```bsh
if [[ ! -p "in" ]]; then mkfifo "in"; fi

while true; do
  nc -Ul sock >> "out"
done
```

I'm stuck on how to get the input from the FIFO into `netcat`. When I add `< "in"` and try to connect to the socket from another shell the connection is refused. Strangely enough, it works just fine when I replace "in" with a regular file.

What's the easiest / correct way to do this?

**Edit:** Using the pipes on the whole `while` block has the same effect.

Comment: How is `in` used there? Which other application use it on the other end?

Comment: `in` is the name of the FIFO. There isn't another application using it at the moment because I can't get it to pipe into `netcat` correctly.

Comment: I think `nc` would hold itself until some other applications starts writing output to `in`.

Comment: That's the thing. It's not. I'm very confused.

Comment: It seems like the moment I try to involve the FIFO it dies.

Comment: What I mean is if you do `nc -Ul sock < "in" >> "out"`, the socket won't be opened until other application open `"in"` on the other end e.g. `cat > "in"`.  This is the reason why you get a connection refused when you try to connect to the socket it hasn't opened yet.

Comment: A named pipe is not activated until two processes read and write on it. With only one process trying to open it, that one process would just hang.

Comment: How would I combat that? I tried doing `echo -n "" > "in"` but that caused the attempted socket connection to close instantly.

Comment: Upon further research, `echo` tends to shut things off with an end of file character. I've finally achieved a level of success using `cat > "in"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use some "proxy" to input. For example "cat":

```
if [[ ! -p "in" ]]; then mkfifo "in"; fi

(while true; do cat in; done) | (while true; do
  nc -Ul sock >> "out"
done)
```